# Find the element in one array, which has the minimal absolute value

Tags: c++

I am trying to find one element in one array, which has the minimum absolute value. For example, in array [5.1, -2.2, 8.2, -1, 4, 3, -5, 6], I want get the value -1. I use following code (**myarray** is 1D array and not sorted)

```
for (int i = 1; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        if(fabsf(myarray[i])<fabsf(myarray[0])) myarray[0] = myarray[i];
    }
```

Then, the target value is in **myarray[0]**.
Because I have to repeat this procedure many times, this piece of code becomes the bottleneck in my program. Does anyone know how to improve this code? Thanks in advance!

BTW, the size of the array is always **eight**. Could this be used to optimize this code?

Update: so far, following code works slightly better on my machine:

```
float absMin = fabsf(myarray[0]); int index = 0; 
for (int i = 1; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        if(fabsf(myarray[i])<absMin) {absMin = fabsf(myarray[i]); index=i;}
    }
float result = myarray[index];
```

I am wandering how to avoid **fabsf**, because I just want to **compare** the absolute values instead of **computing** them. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Why not keep the absolute minimum for the array and only recalculate it when things are removed. When things added just a simple comparison and an update for the current minimum value may be required

Comment: Keep track of the absolute valut of array[0] so you don't recalculate it each loop.

Comment: If you only care about the min/max value in a data set, consider using a `heap`. It finds the min/max in `O(1)`, inserts in `O(logN)` and deletes `O(logN)`

Comment: The code is already optimal. As pointed out by others, f you want to improve performance you'll need a different approach (e.g. a better data structure).

Comment: @NickZuber, I don't need the min or max value. Instead, I need the value that has minimum absolute value. For example, in [-1,2,3,4], I will get -1, instead of 1.

Comment: @EdHeal, yes, it makes the code a little bit faster. Thanks! Any other idea?

Comment: @88877, yes,  it makes the code a little bit faster. Thanks! Any other idea?

Comment: @Yuanhao You can still use a heap but just determine the "min" element as the one with the lowest absolute value. Are you familiar with heaps (if not I could post an answer with a heap implementation) or am I misunderstanding your problem?

Comment: @NickZuber, the task is to find the value that has minimal absolute value. For example, in array [-2, 2, -1, 4, 3], the target value is -1, which is NOT the min absolute value 1. If heap implementation could do this, please post your answer and the comparison on your machine. I will also test them on my machine.

Comment: @Yuanhao, I think **Nick** understands what you're trying to do but once you keep track the min, you can also track the index assuming you are not modifying the actual data.

Comment: @Yuanhao Should your code be running on multiple machine or just one? If just one could you give me the assembler language used(most likely x86 but who know what fancy stuff you can be doing :) )? Else what are the value contained by your array? If it is something complex, you could try to use multithreading sort (if you have many processor or more than one core by processor)? If it is not you could try to write your own abs function and to compare it to the standard one.

Comment: If you can assume x86 hardware then you can probably make this faster using SSE or AVX (ditto for any other architecture with SIMD support, e.g. ARM + NEON, PowerPC + AltiVec, etc).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't just try it out myself, but: since the absolute value is not relevant for the result but only needed for comparison: Could it be faster to use x*x for comparison rather than fabsf(x)?

Comment: @Dirk Herrmann Nah forcing positive value for a float is really simple , on bit change in fact. What we could do is trying to make the compare function better knowing that both member are positive

Comment: @Dirk, it's a new idea. Thanks! But I think x^2 might be much slower than fabsf.

Comment: By the way, your last piece of code does not the same thing as your first example - there are no side effects (overwriting the first value of `myarray`). Is this intended?

Comment: compiled with -O3 both versions are equally fast on my machine...

Answer (score 1):

Let me give some ideas that could help:

```
float minVal = fabsf(myarray[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < 8; ++i)
{
    if(fabsf(myarray[i])<minVal) minVal = fabsf(myarray[i]);
}

myarray[0] = minVal;
```

But compilers nowadays are very smart and you might not get any more speed, as you already get optimized code. It depends on how your mentioned piece of code is called.

Another way to optimize this **maybe** is using C++ and STL, so you can do the following using the typical binary search tree `std::set`:

```
// Absolute comparator for std::set
bool absless_compare(const int64_t &a, const int64_t &b) 
{
   return (fabsf(a) < fabsf(b));
}

std::set<float, absless_compare> mySet = {5.1, -2.2, 8.2, -1, 4, 3, -5, 6};

const float minVal = *(mySet.begin());
```

With this approach by inserting your numbers they are already sorted in ascending order. The less-Comparator is usually a set for the std::set, but you can change it to use something different like in this example. This might help on larger datasets, but you mentioned you only have eight values to compare, so it really will not help.

Eight elements is a very small number, which might be kept in stack with for example the declaration of `std::array<float,8> myarray` close to your sorting function before filling it with data. You should that variants on your full codeset and observe what helps. Of course if you declare `std::array<float,8> myarray` or `float[8] myarray` runtime you should get the same results.

What you also could check is if `fabsf` really uses float as parameter and does not convert your variable to double which would degrade the performance. There is also `std::abs()` which for my understanding deduces the data type, because in C++ you can use templates etc.

If don't want to use fabs obviously a call like this

```
float myAbs(const float val)
{
   return (val<0) ? -val : val;
}
```

or you hack the bit to zero which make your number negative. Either way, I'm pretty sure, that `fabsf` is fully aware of that, and I don't think a code like that will make it faster.

So I would check if the argument is converted to `double`. If you have C99 Standard in your system though, you should not have that issue.

Comment: For all practical purposes, `std::set` is very unlikely to be faster because it must follow pointer chains when inserting numbers, which is just more work on top of the O(nlogn) operations this takes already.

Comment: This seems giving the minimal absolute value. The question is to find the value that has minimal absolute value, which might be negative.

Comment: The fix for that is trivial, Yuanhao.

Comment: @Gerstrong Nothing with std::set is going to be even close to as fast as linear iteration over an array of 8 elements.

Comment: Yes, I know, I wrote that but I don't know the full code around and not sure if always 8 elements are going to be used. So why downvote my answer?

Comment: Could you change your answer such that it does the job? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are some urban myths like inlining, loop unrolling by hand and similar which are supposed to make your code faster. Good news is you don't have to do it, at least if you use -O3 compiler optimization.

Bad news is, if you already use -O3 there is nothing you can do to speed up this function: the compiler will optimize the hell out of your code! For example it will surely do the caching of `fabsf(myarray[0])` as some suggested. The only thing you can achieve with this "refactoring" is to build bugs into your program and make it less readable.

My advice is to look somewhere else for improvements:

1. try to reduce the number of invocations of this code
2. if this code is the bottle neck, than my guess would be that you recalculate the minimal value over and over again (otherwise filling the values into the array would take approximately the same time) - so cache the results of the search
3. shift costs to changing the elements of the array,  for example by using some fancy data structures (heaps, priority_queue) or by tracking the minimum of elements. Lets say your array has only two elements values `[1,2]` so minimum is `1`. Now if you change

   - 2 to 3, you don't have to do anything
   - 2 to 0, you can easily update your minimum to `0`
   - 1 to 3, you have to loop through all elements. But maybe this case is not that often.

Answer (score 1):

Can you store the values pre fabbed?

Also as @Gerstrong mentions, storing the number outside the loop and only calculating it when array changes will give you a boost.

Calling [`partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) or [`nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) will sort the array only so that the correct value is in the right location.

```
std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin(), v.end(), [](float& lhs, float& rhs){
    return fabsf(lhs)<fabsf(rhs);
});
```

Comment: Is this leading to the minimal absolute value? The task is to find the value that has minimal absolute value. So, it could be negative.

Comment: It will partially sort `v`, with the smallest absolute values first.

Comment: @Peter, Thanks, then this code does not do the job, unfortunately.

Comment: It is reasonably straight-forward to extract the first element from a container after sorting it.   So this post provides a starting point.   Or do you insist on being spoon-fed?

Comment: `v.begin()` is the first element or you could use `v.front()` or `v[0]` or `v.at(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

One thought would be to do your comparisons "tournament" style, instead of linearly. In other words, you first compare 1 with 2, 3 with 4, etc. Then you take those 4 elements and do the same thing, and then again, until you only have one element left.

This does not change the number of comparisons. Since each comparison eliminates one element from the running, you will have exactly 7 comparisons no matter what. So why do I suggest this? Because it removes data dependencies from your code. Modern processors have multiple pipelines and can retire multiple instructions simultaneously. However, when you do the comparisons in a loop, each loop iteration depends on the previous one. When you do it tournament style, the first four comparisons are completely independent, so the processor may be able to do them all at once.

In addition to doing that, you can compute all the fabs at once in a trivial loop and put it in a new array. Since the fabs computations are independent, this can get sped up pretty easily. You would do this first, and then the tournament style comparisons to get the index. It should be exactly the same number of operations, it's just changing the order around so that the compiler can more easily see larger blocks that lack data dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

> The element of an array with minimal absolute value

Let the array, `A`

```
A = [5.1, -2.2, 8.2, -1, 4, 3, -5, 6]
```

The minimal absolute value of `A` is,

```
double miniAbsValue = A.array().abs().minCoeff();
int i_minimum = 0;  // to find the position of minimum absolute value
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
 {
  double ftn = evalsH(i);
  if( fabs(ftn) == miniAbsValue )
    {
      i_minimum =  i; 
    }
  }
```

Now the element of `A` with minimal absolute value is

```
A(i_minimum)
```